# Router firewall and ping of death

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, firewall, ping

I have been studying the Wi-Fi network of the university residence where I live for a network project. I saw that we were limited with the speed of the internet to 10Mbps by IP. 
And now I am trying to find the possible errors that creates the internet connection to be horrible and really slow from time to time.

One of my possible answers to the problem is that the net could be saturated sometimes. Although, I suppose, it would not be happening due to the bandwidth limitation by IP that we have to avoid the network congestion.

I can not understand why if we have that limitation it is possible to launch anywhere on the net, for instance, a "ping of death" without being limited to 10Mbps. It is true (and obvious) that when it is launched the attack, the computer affected can not surf the web because of the slowness.

The command use for the ping of death is the following:

```
sudo ping -f -s 65506 <any IP address>
```

> My doubt is, the very large ICMP packets should they be limited by the
>   firewall limitation as any tcp/http download/upload or can they bypass
>   the firewall limitation?

Moreover, the router does not block the ping, which I think that is not very secure. I post the router nmap, maybe it tells something "interesting":

```
nmap/router 172.17.0.1
Nmap scan report for 172.17.0.1
Host is up (0.0057s latency).
Not shown: 997 filtered ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE        VERSION
443/tcp  open  ssl/http-proxy Cyberoam captive portal
|_http-server-header: xxxx
| http-title: Cyberoam
|_Requested resource was https://172.17.0.1/corporate/webpages/login.jsp
| ssl-cert: Subject: commonName=CyberoamApplianceCertificate_C20315405493/organizationName=Cyberoam/stateOrProvinceName=Gujarat/countryName=IN
| Not valid before: 2015-10-19T18:33:42
|_Not valid after:  2036-12-31T18:33:42
|_ssl-date: TLS randomness does not represent time
3128/tcp open  squid-http?
| http-open-proxy: Potentially OPEN proxy.
|_Methods supported: GET HEAD CONNECTION
8090/tcp open  opsmessaging?
MAC Address: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (CASwell)
Warning: OSScan results may be unreliable because we could not find at least 1 open and 1 closed port
Device type: phone|general purpose
Running: Google Android 7.X, Linux 3.X|2.6.X
OS CPE: cpe:/o:google:android:7.1.2 cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:3.10 cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:2.6
OS details: Android 7.1.2 (Linux 3.10), Linux 2.6.18 - 2.6.22
Network Distance: 1 hop
```

Comment: Big telcos generally drop ICMP from coming in, others limit your ICMP size, so even if you launch a ping request with big payload, it will be dropped at the receiving end.

Comment: @user1007727 thank you, but should the limitation of the network bandwidth affect to the ICMP packetes? I mean the speed will be limited if I send any other type of packets, such as TCP/HTTP. What happens with the ICMP ones? Are they limited to 10Mbps too?